# monodevelop/monotouch installation folder in OSX

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I've created a monotouch project in monodevelop, and if I open it with notepad(or whatever that is in OSX), I can see the msbuild file import tasks from 
Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"
and
Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"

Where are these files located in OSX?
I'm trying to understand how the build process work in monodevelop to make it behave as I want.
I probably do not need to modify those files, but I want to understand how those files are.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, assuming you're using the default Mono framework installer, and assuming the project has a ToolsVersion of 3.5, `$(MSBuildToolsPath)` and `$(MSBuildBinPath)` are both `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/3.5`

However, these don't actually apply to MonoTouch, for two reasons:

1. MonoDevelop currently uses its internal build engine by default, not MSBuild/xbuild. The MSBuild engine can be enabled in MD preferences but is experimental, and only works for projects with supported targets.
2. There are no MSBuild targets for MonoTouch projects yet. This is planned to be fixed as MD gradually migrates to full MSBuild support, but when it is, the imports will be changed to import MonoTouch-specific targets.

You can see the MonoDevelop side of the MonoTouch build code [in the MD source repository](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/extras/MonoDevelop.IPhone/MonoDevelop.IPhone/IPhoneBuildExtension.cs).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is the internal build engine customizable can yo point me to any documntation? is xbuild the msbuild clone? or something different? sorry for the stupid questions

Comment: Yes, xbuild is the msbuild clone. The internal MonoDevelop build engine is customizable to some extent - you can write an addin to add a ProjectServiceExtension - but it's not documented.

Comment: @mhutch, a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695233/how-do-i-make-the-msbuild-task-in-monos-xbuild-use-the-net-3-5-framework) goes back to 2010. When is this likely to occur? And in the meantime, how difficult might it be for a relative newbie to modify the existing Mono targets to work with MonoTouch? This is a pretty big deal...